# Use pstree inside awk command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, pstree

I want to run `pstree` on a set of pid which I find using `ps`

```
ps -aux | grep ^username | awk '{pstree $2}'
```

Unfortunately, the output is empty, but if I run the `pstree` command manually with the same pids I get the desired output. What is wrong with the `awk` command? Or how do I achieve the desired result by other means?

Comment: As an aside, `man ps` would tell you: Note that __"ps -aux"__ is distinct from __"ps aux"__.

Comment: `ps -a -u username -x -o pid` should return the same output as the given pipeline (at least for BSD `ps`; the program varies greatly from platform to platform).

Comment: What happens if you run pstree inside a C program? I'd imagine the result would be identical to that wouldn't it since neither awk nor C are shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `system` function in awk like this:

```
awk '{system("pstree " $2)}'
```

You can shorten your command to:

```
ps -aux | awk ' /^username/ { system("pstree " $2) }'
```

Comment: Great! this is what worked for me
`ps -aux | grep ^username | awk '{system("pstree "$2)}'`

Comment: @e271p314: You can also shorten your command as in my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  ps -aux | grep ^username | awk '{print $2}' | xargs pstree
```

(As is, pstree is an empty variable value )

This can  can be boiled down to

```
ps -aux |  awk '/^username/{print $2}' | xargs pstree
```

IHTH

Comment: +1 for separating the call to `pstree` from the call to `awk` (which prompted my comment on using `ps` alone to get the desired PIDs).

Comment: There you go - an actual UNIX solution with every command doing what it's intended for and is good at!

Comment: High praise from 2 gurus,  :-!  Thanks and Good luck to all!

Answer (score 2):

use the `system` function in `awk`. Also you dont need `grep` here too

```
ps -aux | awk '$1=="username"{system("pstree $2")}'
```